# storage_billing_model usage in bq command

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hi Im executing this command for creating a dataset and getting this below error

"
bq --location=asia-southeast2 mk -d --description="BigQuery Dataset prd_xldf_stg_tb" --label=bilable:true  --label=env:dev --storage_billing_model=PHYSICAL ht-xl-357708:test_schema2
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'storage_billing_model'
Run 'bq.py help' to get help
"
Without the storage_billing_modelthis command is executing fine but as per the documentation Im doing the correct thing
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#mk-dataset.

Can anyone help me here with this?

Hi Im executing this command for creating a dataset and getting this below error

"
bq --location=asia-southeast2 mk -d --description="BigQuery Dataset prd_xldf_stg_tb" --label=bilable:true  --label=env:dev --storage_billing_model=PHYSICAL ht-xl-357708:test_schema2
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'storage_billing_model'
Run 'bq.py help' to get help
"
Without the storage_billing_modelthis command is executing fine but as per the documentation Im doing the correct thing
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#mk-dataset.

Can anyone help me here with this?

Answer (score 0):

For now, as you can see in the documentation, this feature is in "Preview" and can be used only in test environment. More about [Preview Features](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/beta-support)